# Map<String, Map> getting emptied, if inner map is cleared, in a loop

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I get values from DB, and create a Map(String,Map(String,String))

Ex : Map1(001, Map2(Sep-2015,11))
I collect all the months for an Id_No(say 001, contains Jan,Sep,Oct) in the Inner MAP, and save the inner map to outer map.

I Clear() the innerMap to get the next Id_No. But, in turn, the OuterMap is also getting Emptied.
Please suggest an idea. Thanks for your time and help.

DB Data Format:

```
ID_NO   DATE        USAGE

001     Sep-2015    11
001     Oct-2015    12 
001     Jan-2016    68  
008     Feb-2015    4       
008     Mar-2015    2       
008     Sep-2015    5       
012     Feb-2015    16  
012     Mar-2015    20  
012     May-2015    21  
012     Jun-2015    25
012     Sep-2015    22  
012     Oct-2015    26  
028     Jan-2016    29
028     Feb-2015    20  
028     Mar-2015    25
```

My Java Code:

```
    Map<String ,Map> idMap = new HashMap<String, Map>();
    Map<String,String> usageId = new HashMap<String,String>();

   while (resultSet.next()){

        String id = resultSet.getString(1);

        if(("").equals(id1)){
            id1=id;
            id2=id;
        }
        if(!(id2.equals(id))){
            usageId.clear();
            System.out.println("usageId After Clear : "+idMap);
            System.out.println("idMap After Clear : "+idMap);
            usageId.put(resultSet.getString(2),resultSet.getString(3));
            System.out.println("usageId NOT : "+usageId);
            id2=id;
        }else{
            usageId.put(resultSet.getString(2),resultSet.getString(3));
            System.out.println("usageId EQL : "+usageId);
            id2=id;
        }
        idMap.put(id2,usageId);
        System.out.println("idMap : "+idMap);
    }
```

Output:

```
usageId NOT: {Sep-2015=11}
usageId EQL: {Sep-2015=11, oct-2015=12}
usageId EQL: {Sep-2015=11, oct-2015=12, Jan-2015=68}
idMap : {001={Sep-2015=11, oct-2015=12, Jan-2015=68}}
usageId After CLEAR : {}
idMap After CLEAR : {001={}}


usageId NOT: {Feb-2015=4}
usageId EQL: {Feb-2015=4, Mar-2015=2}
usageId EQL: {Feb-2015=4, Mar-2015=2, Sep-2015=5}
idMap : {001={Feb-2015=4, Mar-2015=2, Sep-2015=5},008={Feb-2015=4, Mar-2015=2, Sep-2015=5}}
usageId After CLEAR : {}
idMap After CLEAR : {001={},008={}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `idMap.put()`, it's not *copying* the data from `usageId`; it's putting a *reference* to `usageId` into `idMap`. Since you never update the `usageId` reference, every entry in `idMap` is pointing to the same object, which is being repeatedly overwritten and cleared.

If you want to keep separate data for each entry in `idMap`, just change

```
usageId.clear();
```

to

```
usageId = new HashMap<String,String>();
```

This way, each entry in the outer map will reference a separate map instance with its own data.

Comment: Thank you Shmosel. It Works!